# how to access a value in a nested array in an array php

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, plpgsql

```
Array
(
    [0] => 554
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 298
        )
 )
```

This is how the array looks like.

```
function canSatisfy($db,$code,$ruleID,$enrolment)
{
      echo "second element is $enrolment[1][0]\n";
      return false;
}
```

in the function signature, $enrolment is the array shown above.

I only want to access the value "298", but the output is "second element is Array[0] rather than 298."

what's wrong with it and what should I do?

Comment: use `echo "second element is {$enrolment[1][0]}\n";`

Comment: Can I ask why it is wrong when curly brace is not added?

Comment: Your code needs to go in the question as text, not as images, for your question to be on-topic here.

Comment: It's because you're converting an array type towards a string type. If you had error reporting enabled with notices, it would've told you this: _"E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Array to string conversion -- at line xx"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by couple of ways. Otherwise for multidimensional array you'll get **E_NOTICE**

```
Array to string conversion
```

**Way1**: using concatenation operator `.`

```
$enrollment = [554,[298]];
function canSatisfy($enrollment){
    echo "second element is ". $enrollment[1][0]; // concatenate 
}

canSatisfy($enrollment);
```

**Way2** using complex curly brace `{}` to enclose variable

```
$enrollment = [554,[298]];
function canSatisfy($enrollment){
    echo "second element is {$enrollment[1][0]}"; // using curly braces 
}

canSatisfy($enrollment);
```

See the **Complex (curly) syntax** on http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: It's cool to tell OP how to do it right. But your answer lacks any explanation on _why_ it doesn't work for OP. Like array to string conversion.

Comment: If I want to take the whole array $enrolmemnt[1] as a parameter and put it into a plpgsql function, can I do this?  `$q ="select * from f(%s)"`,        `$r = dbOneValue($db, mkSQL($q, $enrolment[1]))`;